# achieve (property1 + property2) like 'someValue' operation using hibernate criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

My table contains separate columns for firstName and lastName, but i am sending entire name to my DAO layer(cant split up name field to firs and last name in jsp as per requirements).
I want to know whether we can achieve something like:

```
whereClause.append(" and upper(a.given_name + ' ' + a.family_name) like "
                          + someValues);
```

using Restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would be better handled by a Controller utility method or else by a Service layer in your application. Your DAO shouldn't have to care about the details of your UI implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have lookup by composed string (firstname + secondname) then you can create one more column specifically for this purpose. Its value you can pre-calculate at user creation/update time.